# --bitcode is not a valid argument when building WebRTC for ios

Tags: webrtc

I am currently trying to build a WebRTC framework and need bitcode. In the official documents from WebRTC it indicates to use the --bitcode argument.

https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/native-code/ios/

However, when run this command `python build_ios_libs.py --bitcode` it gives me this message `build_ios_libs.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --bitcode`.

So it leads me to ask two questions:

1. Does WebRTC automatically build bitcode into the framework file?
2. If it doesn't how would I get it into the framework?

I tried searching the official instructions on any updates, and I have not seen any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcode is no longer supported in recent versions:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=14237

webrtc.github.io is no longer maintained, refer to the git repo for updated information: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/native-code/ios/

Comment: Thanks! I really wish they would update the other documentation to make it consistent.